# How to put a video texture on gltf model in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe, gltf

I want to play a video on a gltf model in A-Frame.  The video plays on a box just fine, but when I put the video asset on the model, I can only hear the audio and do not see the video.

I've searched the slack and now stack overflow, but haven't found either a way to do it or the reason why I can't.  Maybe it has to do with https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/developers/library/2018-gdc-webgl-and-gltf/glTF-Texture-Transmission-GDC_Mar18.pdf ?

This glitch has the model and the material (not working): glitch.com/~dusty-warm-turner

Here is the code:

```
> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Video on Lotus</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      
     
  <a-assets>
     <a-asset-item id="lotus" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/ba9173ee-5c4e-4f9d-82dc-70aca80f9645%2Fwhitetex_lotus.glb?v=1598900627603"></a-asset-item>
    <video id="concert" autoplay loop="true" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/c19d442b-56a3-4fd1-842e-c603b0f7ceea%2FDM829_CONCERT.mp4?v=1598804380280"></video>
 
 </a-assets>
      <a-entity gltf-model="#lotus" color="#FFC65D" material="src:#concert" position="0 0.5 -5"></a-entity>
  <a-entity geometry="primitive: box" position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0"></a-entity>
      <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" material="src:#concert" shadow></a-cylinder>
      <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" shadow></a-plane>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi! Please share some code so that others can reproduce the problem and try to help you.

Comment: Looking at the model and how you're applying the texture will help people understand.

Comment: Hi @DonMcCurdy here are the glitch links: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/tattered-sweet-chicken and https://glitch.com/edit/#!/dusty-warm-turner

Comment: Hi @DiegoMarcos This glitch has the model and the material (not working): https://glitch.com/~dusty-warm-turner